# "v-for" of Vue.js outputs error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js v1.0.21 and trying to print buttons.

```
html:
...
<span id="buttons" v-for="button in buttons" track-by="$index">
  <input type="button" value="{{ button.label }}" />
</span>
...

js:
var v = new Vue({
    el: '#buttons',
    data: {
        buttons: [
            { label: 'foo' },
            { label: 'bar' },
            { label: 'baz' },
        ],
    },
});
```

When I execute this code, 3 buttons are printed correctly. But, error 'Error when evaluating expression "button.label": TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined' appeared in my console.

Is there any mistake in this code ?

Comment: Just tried this in a fiddle, it works fine. Maybe your error comes from another part of your code? https://jsfiddle.net/socjrhyk/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I don't know why it works, but I updated html as follows and worked fine.

    <span id="buttons>
      <span v-for="button in buttons" track-by="$index">
        <input type="button" value="{{ button.label }}" />
      </span>
    </span>

Comment: @nils it's only a warning, so it's suppressed if you use vue.min.js. If you take your fiddle and use vue.js instead, you see the error in question: https://jsfiddle.net/bkau0xnd/1/